# Why adding html to textarea gets first img with undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textarea and a bunch of images as checkboxes replacement, when I click on one of it, this will be added with extra markup as plain text into the textarea:

HTML

```
<textarea name="usp-custom-4" id="usp-custom-4" data-required="false" placeholder="Example Input 4" data-richtext="false" class="usp-input usp-textarea usp-form-16" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea>
```

JS

```
 jQuery.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
    var uniq = uniqueId('thing_');
    var $items = jQuery(
      '<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 grid-item">'.concat(
        '<div class="thumbnail">',
          '<input type="checkbox" name="', uniq, '" value="valuable" id="', uniq, '" />',
          '<label for="', uniq, '">',
            '<img class="img-responsive" src="' + item.link + '">',
          '</label>',
        '</div>',
      '</div>')
    );
    jQuery('body').on('change', '.grid .thumbnail :checkbox', function () {
      var urls = [];
      jQuery(':checkbox:checked').each(function () {
        urls.push(jQuery(this).next('label').find('img').attr('src'));
      });
      var str = '';
      urls.forEach(function (url) {
        str += '<div class="carousel-cell"><img class="carousel-cell-image" onerror="this.parentNode.removeChild(this);" data-flickity-lazyload="' + url + '"></div>';
      });
      jQuery('#usp-custom-4').val(str);
    });
 });
```

If I select one or 2 images, the first html i get is always coming with a data attribute with an undefined value

```
<div class="carousel-cell">
    <img class="carousel-cell-image" onerror="this.parentNode.removeChild(this);" data-flickity-lazyload="undefined">
</div>
<div class="carousel-cell">
    <img class="carousel-cell-image" onerror="this.parentNode.removeChild(this);" data-flickity-lazyload="https://profgiovannafraccalvieri.files.wordpress.com/2016/04/impero-romano-2012.jpg?w=812">
</div>
<div class="carousel-cell">
    <img class="carousel-cell-image" onerror="this.parentNode.removeChild(this);" data-flickity-lazyload="http://www.skuola.net/news_foto/2016/divisione-impero-romano.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: A JSFiddle will be great!

Comment: What is `data.items`?

Comment: Why are setting the event listener inside `each`??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bit of code below will select all checked checkboxes on the page, not just your `'.grid .thumbnail :checkbox'` Is it possible there is another checkbox on the page that does not have a label and img to go with it?

```
 jQuery(':checkbox:checked').each(function () {
```

Comment: that was indeed what! Thanks a lot, changed into the full path and worked